# Spring Boot JWT Authentication Filter Works for GET But Not for POST Requests

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

I'm working on a POC Spring Boot application with JWT-based authentication. I've implemented a custom authentication filter to validate JWT tokens and refresh them when they expire. The filter works as expected for GET requests, but I'm encountering an issue with POST requests.

In my AuthTokenFilter class, I have a doFilterInternal method that correctly validates and processes JWT tokens. However, when I make POST requests, the filter does not seem to be invoked, and I'm getting "Unauthorized" errors.

I have checked my CORS configuration, and it doesn't seem to be the issue since GET requests work fine. I have also verified that the JWT tokens and refresh tokens are correctly included in the requests.

Can anyone please help me identify why the doFilterInternal method is not being triggered for POST requests? Are there any specific configurations or settings that I might be missing for POST requests? I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue. Thank you.

THis is the controller where get is working fine but POST is not

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping("/api/owner")
public class PostOwnerController {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PostOwnerController.class);

    @Autowired
    PostOwnerService postOwnerService;


    @GetMapping("/api/")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('OWNER')")
    public String test(){
        return "Shubham";
    }
    @PutMapping("/updateMenu")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('OWNER')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateMenu(@RequestBody MenuManagementModel updatedMenu) {
        try {
            MenuManagementModel updated = postOwnerService.updateExistingMenu(updatedMenu);
            if (updated != null) {
                logger.info("Menu updated successfully: {}", updated);
                return ResponseEntity.ok(updated);
            } else {
                logger.warn("Menu not found for id:{} ", updatedMenu.getId());
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Menu not found with ID: " + updatedMenu.getId());
            }
        } catch (OperationFailedException e) {
            logger.warn("Error while updating menu: {}", e.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error while updating a menu: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code from WebSecurityConfig

```
@Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(toH2Console())
                    .ignoringRequestMatchers("/api/auth/**"))
            .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/owner/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/v1/user/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(toH2Console()).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            );
}
```

Comment: Your controller method is annotated with `@PutMapping`, so it serves PUT requests, not POST requests.